# Matplotlib imshow() error

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I dont know what is is wrong with this.I have this mgrib with a z value

```
pp=array(Arrays)  #This is my Array that extract a Grid

y,x=np.mgrid[slice(0,25, 1),slice(0,42, 1)]
z=pp[y,x,1]  #Extract Z with x,y position in the Array of pp
```

When execute:

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Azul-Rojo-Alpha')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmax=pp[:,:,1].max(), vmin=pp[:,:,1].min())
plt.imshow(z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='nearest')
```

Give me this error:

```
ValueError: data mapping points must start with x=0. and end with x=1
```

If check and the error is here:

```
cdict1 = {
'red':   (( 0.0, 0.0, (7.0/255.0)),
        (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

'green': ((0.0, 0.0,    (183.0/255.0)),
         (0.0, (44.0/255.0), 1)),

'blue':  ((0.0, 0.0,1.0),
             (1.0, 0.0, 1.0))
}
cdict1['alpha'] = ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                           (0.5, 0.0, 0.0),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
TEMPE = LinearSegmentedColormap('Azul-Rojo-Alpha', cdict1)  
plt.register_cmap(cmap=TEMPE)
```

But I dont know why.

Sorry my english

Comment: It seems like your normalization isn't working properly for some reason.. but I can't say much more.

Comment: Sorry I incorporate more info

Answer (score 0):

Hello I answer my question. I think that is syntax error.

Create a Dictionary with two colors

```
cdict1 = {
'red':   (( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.717),(1.0, 0.17, 0.17)),
'blue':  ((0.0, 1.0,1.0),(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))}
```

Put alpha channel with 3 points

```
cdict1['alpha'] = ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),(0.5, 0.0, 0.0),(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
```

Create colorMap

```
TEMPE = LinearSegmentedColormap('Azul-Rojo-Alpha', cdict1,N=256,gamma=0.75)
```

Register color Map

```
plt.register_cmap(name='temp',cmap=TEMPE)
```

Normalice Color to max and min of the grid

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmax=pp[:,:,1].max(), vmin=pp[:,:,1].min(), clip = True)
```

Call color map

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('temp')
```

Create Image

```
plt.imshow(z[::-1], cmap=TEMPE, norm=norm , interpolation='nearest') #extent=[0,42,0,25]
```